# Сложный sql запрос с вложенностью в select. Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос. И одно из полей в *select* должно собираться вложенным *select*. Выглядит это так:

```
SELECT m.PIPE_NUMBER,
       m.PIPE_YEAR,
       s.WC_INSTANCE,
       r.WORKCENTER_ID,
       s.RETURN_REASON,
       m.DIAMETER,
       m.THICKNESS,
       m.MELT_NUMBER,
       m.PART_WELD,
       m.STEELMARK,
       m.VENDER,
       s.WAREHOUSE_BEFORE_MOVING,
       s.ORDER_NUM_RES || '-' || s.ORDER_ITEM_RES AS res_und_order,
       s.CREATE_DATE,
       s.INSERT_OPERATOR,
(
    SELECT p.CREATE_DATE
    FROM WC_MAIN ma
         LEFT JOIN WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p ON ma.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID
                                       AND ma.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR
                                       AND ma.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
         LEFT JOIN WC_7_3_SGP s ON ma.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID
                                   AND ma.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR
                                   AND ma.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
    WHERE s.ORDER_NUM_RES IS NULL
          AND s.ORDER_ITEM_RES IS NULL
          AND p.EDIT_STATE = 0
          AND s.EDIT_STATE = 0
          AND m.EDIT_STATE = 0
          AND ma.PIPE_NUMBER = m.PIPE_NUMBER
          AND p.WC_INSTANCE = s.WC_INSTANCE
    GROUP BY p.CREATE_DATE,
             s.CREATE_DATE
    HAVING MIN(p.CREATE_DATE) >= MAX(s.CREATE_DATE)
) AS DATE_CANCEL_RESERV
FROM WC_MAIN m
     LEFT JOIN WC_1_2_LIST l ON m.SHOP_ID = l.SHOP_ID
                                AND m.PIPE_YEAR = l.PIPE_YEAR
                                AND m.PIPE_NUMBER = l.PIPE_NUMBER
     LEFT JOIN WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p ON m.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID
                                   AND m.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR
                                   AND m.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
     LEFT JOIN WC_7_3_SGP s ON m.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID
                               AND m.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR
                               AND m.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
     LEFT JOIN ROUTE_PIPE_MOVES r ON m.SHOP_ID = r.SHOP_ID
                                     AND m.PIPE_YEAR = r.PIPE_YEAR
                                     AND m.PIPE_NUMBER = r.PIPE_NUMBER
WHERE m.EDIT_STATE = 0
      AND p.EDIT_STATE = 0
      AND l.EDIT_STATE = 0
      AND s.EDIT_STATE = 0
      AND r.EDIT_STATE = 0
      AND r.ACTION = 'MOVE';
```

Но выдаёт ошибку что не найдено ключевое слово *from*. Что я делаю не так?

---

И сразу вторая часть вопроса. Во вложенном *select* есть такое условие как `AND m.PIPE_NUMBER = 252081`. Как можно передавать в него для каждой строчки собирающийся в первом *select*'е `m.PIPE_NUMBER` соответственно для каждой выбранной строчки свой? Если не сложно, отразите ответы на примере моего запроса.

**Запрос:**

```
SELECT p.row_id,
       p.row_date,
       p.row_mode,
       p.rec_id,
       p.edit_state,
       p.operator_id,
       p.shop_id,
       p.pipe_year,
       p.pipe_number,
       p.batch_id,
       p.wc_instance,
       p.aggr_id,
       p.create_date,
       s.row_id,
       s.row_date,
       s.row_mode,
       s.rec_id,
       s.edit_state,
       s.operator_id,
       s.shop_id,
       s.pipe_year,
       s.pipe_number,
       s.batch_id,
       s.wc_instance,
       s.aggr_id,
       s.create_date
FROM WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p
     JOIN WC_7_3_SGP s ON p.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID
                          AND p.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR
                          AND p.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
WHERE p.PIPE_NUMBER = 64440
      AND p.WC_INSTANCE = s.WC_INSTANCE
GROUP BY p.row_id,
         p.row_date,
         p.row_mode,
         p.rec_id,
         p.edit_state,
         p.operator_id,
         p.shop_id,
         p.pipe_year,
         p.pipe_number,
         p.batch_id,
         p.wc_instance,
         p.aggr_id,
         p.create_date,
         s.row_id,
         s.row_date,
         s.row_mode,
         s.rec_id,
         s.edit_state,
         s.operator_id,
         s.shop_id,
         s.pipe_year,
         s.pipe_number,
         s.batch_id,
         s.wc_instance,
         s.aggr_id,
         s.create_date
HAVING MIN(p.CREATE_DATE) > MAX(s.CREATE_DATE)
ORDER BY p.wc_instance;
```

**Выборка:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63481/discussion-on-question-by---sql-----select-ora).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По второй части вопроса, я бы пошел по такому пути:

```
SELECT min(p.create_date) keep(dense_rank first order by s.create_date desc)
  FROM WC_7_3_SGP s
  LEFT JOIN WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p
    ON p.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID AND p.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR AND p.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
   AND p.WC_INSTANCE = s.WC_INSTANCE
   AND p.create_date >= s.create_date
 WHERE s.PIPE_NUMBER = 64440
```

В данном случае мы используем LEFT JOIN что бы в случае если на приемке записи с подходящей датой еще нет, в выборке присутствовала бы запись из SGP со своей s.create_date, но с NULL в дате приемки. `min() keep(dense_rank first)` возвращает минимальную дату приемки на самую первую дату SGP в порядке указанной сортировки (по убыванию даты SGP, т.е. максимальной).

Внимание: в связи с использованием LEFT JOIN запрос должен быть составлен так, что бы в части WHERE не присутствовало ни одного условия по таблице `p`. Все условия, касающиеся этой таблицы должны быть в части `ON`.